# Flushing the png device in plot_grid (using cowplot)

Tags: r, ggplot2, cowplot

Here is my problem:

I do :

```
plot_grid(first_graph_by_mistake)
plot_grid(second_graph_on_purpuse)
ggsave("graph1.png")
```

vs ONLY

```
plot_grid(second_graph_on_purpose)
ggsave("graph2.png")
```

both the graphs look the same but when I do:

```
system("diff graph1.png graph2.png") it shows a difference.
```

Perhaps the png device is not flushed and some settings are different and that is why diff is showing a difference. How can I make the 2 graphs exactly the same ? That is my MAIN query.

I did the above in a very long piece of code. When I  try to make a reprex example the diff does not show any difference between the 2 graphs. I am UNABLE to reproduce what I refer to in my query.

Here is the reprex:

```
library(cowplot)
library(grid)

plot.mpg.1 <- ggplot(mpg, aes(x = cty, y = hwy, colour = factor(cyl)))   + geom_point(size=2.5)
plot.mpg.2 <- ggplot(mpg, aes(x = cty, y = displ, colour = factor(cyl))) + geom_point(size  = 2.5)
plot.mpg.3 <- ggplot(mpg, aes(x = hwy, y = displ, colour = factor(cyl))) + geom_point(size  = 2.5)
plot.mpg.4 <- ggplot(mpg, aes(x = drv, y = displ, colour = factor(cyl))) + geom_point(size  = 2.5)

mygraphs <- list(plot.mpg.1,plot.mpg.2,plot.mpg.3,plot.mpg.4)
dummygraph <- mygraphs[[1]]    
legend = get_legend(dummygraph + theme(legend.position = "bottom",legend.justification="center") + guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow =  1 )))

toplotlist <- lapply(mygraphs,function(x){x + theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0, 0, 0,0), "in"),legend.position="none")})

pmatrix  <-  do.call("plot_grid",toplotlist)
p<-plot_grid(pmatrix,legend,nrow=2,rel_heights = c(8,.2),rel_widths = c(10,1))

# Note : Please run first, the first section. Then run the second section. 


######################################################################################################
# Without this line
#   plot_grid(pmatrix,legend,nrow=2,rel_heights = c(64,1))

title <- ggdraw() + draw_label("My title", fontface='bold',size = 20)
semifinal <-  plot_grid(title, p, ncol=1, rel_heights=c(0.1, 1))
blank <- grid.rect(gp=gpar(col="white"))
plot_grid(semifinal,blank,ncol=1,rel_heights=c(15,1))
ggsave(paste0("without_line.png"),height = 10,width = 10,dpi = 600)             
   ########################################################################### ############################
# With this line  
plot_grid(pmatrix,legend,nrow=2,rel_heights = c(64,1))

title <- ggdraw() + draw_label("My title", fontface='bold',size = 20)
semifinal <-  plot_grid(title, p, ncol=1, rel_heights=c(0.1, 1))
blank <- grid.rect(gp=gpar(col="white"))
plot_grid(semifinal,blank,ncol=1,rel_heights=c(15,1))
ggsave(paste0("with_line.png"),height = 10,width = 10,dpi = 600)             

 ###################################################################################################

# Now do
system("diff without_line.png with_line.png")
```

Comment: I don't understand. Do you have a reprex for the behavior you describe? When I run your code I get two pngs that are identical.

Comment: My reprex FAILS to reproduce the problem I describe.

Comment: Then there's not much we can do. Without reprex, how can we know what you observed wasn't caused by something else you did that you can't remember or didn't notice? Honestly, I don't see how the effect you describe could happen.